# clang-format with better support for nested C++ templates

Tags: c++, clang-format

I'm looking into using clang-format for enforcing C++ code style. It mostly fits my requirements except for the fact that it pretty much has no settings for formatting complex template structures like

```
template<typename ... params> 
    std::enable_if<
        std::is_same<...,...>::value ||
        std::is_same<...,...>::value,
        void>::type
```

Are there any forks of clang-format that give you more control over these constructs?

Any other tools that might do the trick?

Comment: Have you tried getting in touch with the authors?

Comment: Not yet. I assume their position would be (and rightly so) - you want it - you patch it.

Comment: Do you have any news on this issue @Ghostrider?